# Optimize HTML Email

Tags: html, email, optimization

Is there a service that converts HTML (css+html) into email optimized format?

**Edit:** Optimized Means Will Show Same/Similar In 99% of emails

Comment: This is too open of a question and not really related to programming - you should ask this at http://superuser.com/

Comment: just for kicks... what exactly does email optimized mean to you?

Comment: Ok, do you mean HTML from a web site? Perhaps tell us exactly what you're trying to do and in what context and we can recommend a solution?  if you're looking specifically at the conversion, check out what's supported.. there's really not a standard, you tailor it to the email client most of your users will be using: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ basic tags do however work.  Your best bet is to play around with the code till you get it to a consistency that is supported  by your email client and displays the page you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These services do what you want:

- http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css
- http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/

Comment: other resources include: http://premailer.dialect.ca/ - http://www.verticalresponse.com/sites/www.verticalresponse.com/files/html_tips_for_email_guide.pdf - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx - http://emailbg.net/

Comment: sorry for the late reply